# Not able to make WSO2 IS 5.9.0 api's call from React JS application?

Tags: reactjs, axios, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using axios to make api call on react js

```
Headers------>
import axios from 'axios';

const apiURL =
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
? 'https://MY IP:9443/'
: 'https://MY IP:9443/';

const myHeaders = {
Accept: 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic /-My Header converted to base64 with username:password format',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

axios.defaults.baseURL = apiURL;
axios.defaults.headers = myHeaders;

async function post(url, payload = '') {
return await axios.post(`${url}`, payload);
}

export default {
post
};
```

```
API CALL----->
senddata = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({
        handleLoginLoading: true,
    });

    const payload = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    };

    loginApiUrl
      .post('/oauth2/token', payload)
      .then(response => {
          if (response.data.result.type == 'test_taker') {
              this.setLoginParams(response.data.result, this.state.rememberme);
          } else {
              this.setState({
                  showSnackbar: true,
                  snackbarVariant: 'error',
                  snakBarMessage: 'Invalid Login',
                  position: 'center',
                  handleLoginLoading: false,
              });
          }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        handleLoginLoading: false
      });
};
```

My base url is in the form of 'x.x.x.x:9443' where x is a number

Error I am facing is

```
OPTIONS https://IP:9443/oauth2/token net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I am not successful to do so and not able to integrate my web app with identity server

Please help me with my problem and it will be very helpful if you can provide detailed steps????
Thank You

Comment: Are you using the default keystores?

Comment: Chances are this is a self signed certificate that is not accepted by your JS application. The default used by WSO2 is a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a certificate validation issue. Since you are trying to access it locally, temporally solution is to navigate to `https://IP:9443/oauth2/token` or `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token` on browser and add an exception.